# Relation between realizations and its connection with their random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Let $x$ and $y$ be 2 realizations of the continuous RVs $X$ and $Y$, such that $X,Y\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$. Given $x$ (or $y$), if I know that $y$ (or $x$) is bounded by $y>1-x$, does it mean that $Y>1-X$? If so, that would demonstrate that $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ for pairs $(x,y)$ such that $y<1-x$, wouldn't it?

Comment: What is the quantifier in the "bounded by" statement: does it refer to *this particular realization* $(x,y)$ or to *all possible realizations?*

Comment: @whuber Imagine I have a realization of the form $(x,y)$. If I could just know the value of $x$, I would know that $y>1-x$. And the same happens for every possible pair.

Comment: That is *precisely* what the relation $Y \gt 1-X$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For background: [Is that meaningful to compare two random variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29182/is-that-meaningful-to-compare-two-random-variables), in particular, "If X and Y are random variables with values on the real line or any other space that can be ordered then {X>Y} has meaning as a measurable event."

If $y>1-x$ for all x and y, then $Y>1-X$ is an event with the property $P(Y>1-X)=1$.

If $y<1-x$ then $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=0$ as you thought.

Comment: Thank you. As a side note (and unfortunately), we cannot say much about $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ if $y>1-x$, can we?